# How to setup the RTOS Object Viewer on Code Composer Studio?

Tags: texas-instruments, rtos

While configuring Code Composer Studio 9.3 to use RTOS Object Viewer from Texas Instrument I encountered the following error. The computer is running windows 10.

[image: Connect Target]

Below is error in text format

```
js: "C:/ti/xdctools_3_31_00_24_core/packages/xdc/xdc.tci", line 354: xdc.services.global.XDCException: xdc.PACKAGE_NOT_FOUND: can't locate the package 'xdc.rov.monserver' along the path: 

'C:/ti/tirtos_cc13xx_cc26xx_2_21_01_08/packages;C:/ti/tirtos_cc13xx_cc26xx_2_21_01_08/products/tidrivers_cc13xx_cc26xx_2_21_01_01/packages;
C:/ti/tirtos_cc13xx_cc26xx_2_21_01_08/products/bios_6_46_01_38/packages;
C:/ti/tirtos_cc13xx_cc26xx_2_21_01_08/products/uia_2_01_00_01/packages;C:\ti\xdctools_3_31_00_24_core/packages;'. 

Ensure that the package path is set correctly.
```

Below is CCS XDCtools configuration setting

[image: XDSTool Configuration Setting]

The error indicates that the package path has to be set.

Note: RTOS object viewer can be initiated from following menu option on Code Composer Studio 9.3

[image: RTOS Object Viewer]

---

### Question

Can anyone point to the location where the path should be set? Any insight to the content of the path.

---

Comment: This looks like a relevant thread on the TI community forum. https://e2e.ti.com/support/legacy_forums/embedded/tirtos/f/355/t/208491

Comment: @Rustin, Thank you for pointing out.  The post refers to CCS 5.03 Version. I am using CCS 9.3 Version. I think user interface is different. Any thoughts on how it is done in CCS 9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems late but may be helpfull for others. This tread has the solution
https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/other/f/908/t/894003

If you are using XDCtools 3.3x or lower, you need to use ROV Classic as in the following figure.

[image]